# BreadcrumblList JSON-LD Schema Should I include First Home Page in All Category's Page?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search, json-ld, breadcrumbs

I am looking for a perfect website BreadcrumblList JSON-LD for e-commerce

I am read this google article and I got confused https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/breadcrumb

The reason because in real-world people are included home page as well as in Breadcrumb List.

```
Home > Category1 > Category2 > Product3
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
"@context": "https://schema.org",
"@type": "BreadcrumbList",
  "itemListElement": [{
    "@type": "ListItem",
    "position": 1,
    "name": "Category1",
    "item": "https://example.com/Category1"
  },{
    "@type": "ListItem",
    "position": 2,
    "name": "Category 2",
    "item": "https://example.com/books/Category2"
  },{
    "@type": "ListItem",
    "position": 3,
    "name": "Product Page 3",
    "item": "https://example.com/books/authors/Product3"
  }]
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally don't add it, and don't add breadcrumbs to a page unless there is a higher level besides the home page.

Sometimes Google is smart enough to ignore the home page entry, but sometimes it's not, and I don't think it looks good in the snippet:

domain.com > Home > Category1

I think it's neater without it:

domain.com > Category1

The documentation examples do imply that the home page is not included, but there is nothing specifically said about it. I've sent some feedback.